# How to set background image in UIButton of Xamarin.IOS application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image: Left side image in UIButton of Xamrin IOS]

I have tried the code below but text image gets overlapped.

```
btnBack.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Images/arrow-back.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
btnBack.TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal issue when setting text and image simultaneously on Button.

You can use `TitleEdgeInsets` and `ImageEdgeInsets` to get rid of it.

For example:

```
button.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -10, 0, 0);
button.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, -10);
```

Moreover, you can also create a `UIView` which contains image and text, in this way it is more controllable.